# How to pass Asp.Net Web API an angular route

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I am calling a Asp.Net Web Api from angular.

Web Api is secured so its redirect to Login page.
Now after Login I want to redirect to the angular route which has called the API.

Now since angular routes are only at client side, Referer header is always base URL like : https://example.com, its never https://example.com/#/Products/Details. 
How to get this done so that I can redirect to route after successful Login

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do the routing based on result of login. When you're trying to call the api, get the result of login into a variable/object and then depending on the success or failure you can do your routing. It has to be done at the angular side where you're calling the API.

Comment: I already have solution, where I add my route to header, and server keep it as redirect url, after login it redirects to the route. I am looking a solution where referer should be whats in address bar of the browser, which is angular route